# Coq eapply generates a goal with a question mark while proving existence of a function

Tags: coq

I would like to prove that for every group there exists a minus function that takes an element of the group and returns its negative.

My Coq code is as follows:

```
Record Group:Type := {
G:Set;
plus: G->G->G;
O:G;
assoc: forall x y z:G, plus x (plus y z)=plus (plus x y) z;
neut: forall x:G, plus x O=x /\ plus O x=x;
neg: forall x:G, exists y:G, plus x y=O
}.

Lemma minus_exists(H:Group):exists minus_func:G H->G H, (forall x:G H, plus H x (minus_func(x))=O H).
eapply ex_intro.
```

The last tactic generates the following output:

```
  H : Group
  ============================
   forall x : G H, plus H x (?12 x) = O H
```

My first issue is the `?12` which I figure is probably a badly displayed character. What is the meaning of this and is there a way to make it readable.

My second question is how to complete the proof, which might become clearer after the first question is answered.

Comment: Technical info: I run coqtop under a terminal in Ubuntu 16.04, running on an Asus X556-XJ laptop. Using coqide does not change the described phenomenon.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: The only technical info we generally need here is the version of Coq. But indeed I understand that because you thought `?12` was a printing bug, you gave some details on the kind of system.

Comment: Your second question is worth asking as a separate one. Short answer to it: you can't complete the proof, you need to add `neg : G -> G` and its property `neg_prop: forall x:G, exists y:G, plus x (neg x) = O /\ plus (neg x) x = O;` to the record's definition.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Or use an axiom.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. Now that the first question was answered, I understand that I took a wrong path to proving the lemma. I will try to find a different approach, and maybe ask it as separate question later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my Coq version, I get instead:

```
forall x : G H, plus H x (?minus_func x) = O H
```

which is slightly better. In Coq, a term displayed of the form `?T` is what we call a *"meta"* or an *"existential variable"* (evar).

The terminology comes from the field of logic programming and automated theorem proving, and it could be roughly interpreted as representing "an unknown term". Usually, evars play the role of variables in the **unification** process. The whole Coq proof engine is built around this notion of unknown or evar.

In your case, `eapply ex_intro` (or `eexists`) is missing the witness. Coq will create a new "evar" to stand for the missing function, and allows you to continue your proof. Note however that in order to complete the proof, you will need to provide a witness later on.

*How are evars made into actual terms*? The act of replacing an evar by an actual term is known as *"instantiation"*. In many cases, instantiation will be performed by the unification algorithm. For instance, if we had a lemma:

```
Lemma f_plus x : plus H x (f x) = O H
```

we could do `apply f_plus` and `?minus_func` would be replaced by `f`. Another  way is to use the `instantiate` tactic, but it is obsolete these days. In our previous case, you could then write `instantiate (1 := f)` and that would replace `?minus_func` by `f`. Due to technical reasons this approach is not well supported anymore, thus in practice you are bound to either instantiating evars by unification or providing the actual witness to tactics.

I suggest you read a bit more about unification and logic programming.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. How can I get your output? (How to get ?minus_func instead of ?12.) I checked my coq version using coqtop -v `The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (November 2015)
compiled on Nov 04 2015 12:56:53 with OCaml 4.02.3`

Comment: I am using Coq 8.6, I recommend you upgrade, the improvements are massive.

Answer (score 2):

`?12` is not a badly displayed character, it is a *hole*. The `eapply` tactics is a kind of "apply this lemma/hypothesis, but I don't have all the input at hand yet, so please insert holes instead, that I will fill later".

By entering `eapply ex_intro` (or `eexists`) you are just saying "There exists a function which I don't know yet, so please replace it by a hole, I will provide it later". However since the whole purpose of your lemma is to build this function, I'm not sure you are on the right path. Try proving your lemmas without any `efoo` tactics, you don't need them.

Comment: As a comment, I'm not sure you'll be able to do anything with this definition of group, you might need a decidable comparison operator to be able to test any element of `G` against the neutral element.